# How to disallow reprinting of receipts in yii2?

Tags: php, pdf, browser, yii2

I am allowing a user to generate a receipt in PDF format and download. user can download the pdf and then take as many prints as he wants. i want to disallow a user to reprint the receipt.

if i do not allow to generate PDF instead i force user to print directly from browser printing but browser also gives an option to download PDF.

Any solution ?

Comment: Use `jsPDF` with custom controls that does not have print button.

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pdf-viewer-in-javascript--cms-32505